# Unhashable type list python

Tags: python

When i run my program (anagram solver) i get error Unhashable type: list,  thats when i turned wordList into a tuple but i still get the error.

The word.txt contains a bunch of words like so
word.txt

```
abruptly
abruptness
abs
abscam
```

here is code:

```
def main():
    lenWord = 4
    wordList = readMatrix()
    lengthWord(lenWord)

def readMatrix():
    wordList = []
    strFile = open("words.txt", "r")
    lines = strFile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        word = line.rstrip().lower()
        wordList.append(word)
    return tuple(wordList)

def lengthWord(lenWord):
    wordList = readMatrix()
    for word in wordList:
        if len(word) == lenWord:
            sortWord = sorted(word)
            setWord = set(word)
            sortDict = ({sortWord : setWord})
    return sortDict

main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just turn the list back into a string (`str`)

```
sortWord = ''.join(sorted(word))
```

other suitable choices could be `tuple` or `frozenset`

This next line is a bug though - it's just the set of letters

```
setWord = set(word)
```

You'll want to make the value a set containing the actual words.

eg.

```
sortWord = ''.join(sorted(word))
if sortWord not in sortDict:
    sortDict[sortWord] = set()
sortDict[sortWord].add(setWord)
```

Comment: @solofisher, `set('hello world')` gives `set([' ', 'e', 'd', 'h', 'l', 'o', 'r', 'w'])`. You need a set of words eg. `set(['world', 'hello'])`

Answer (score 0):

[`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) inbuilt function in python will return you list.

Your line of code

```
sortWord = sorted(word)
```

will give you `sortWord` as list. You have to convert it to python [hashable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html) object.