# Type Error: unhashable type: list when using Python set of strings

Tags: python, list, nltk

I know there's been several very similar answers here on SO on this exact question, but none of them really answer my question.

I'm trying to remove a series of stop words and punctuation from a list of words to perform basic natural language processing.

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from string import punctuation


    text = "Hello there. I am currently typing Python. "
    custom_stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english')+list(punctuation))

    # tokenizes the text into a sentence
    sentences = sent_tokenize(text)

    # tokenizes each sentence into a list of words
    words = [word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
    filtered_words = [word for word in words if word not in custom_stopwords]
    print(filtered_words)
```

This throws a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` error on the `filtered_words` line. Why is this error being thrown? I'm not providing a `list` collection at all- I'm providing a `set`?

Note: I've read the post on [SO on this exact error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464152/typeerror-unhashable-type-list-when-using-built-in-set-function), but still have the same question. The accepted answer provides this explanation:

> **Sets require their items to be hashable. Out of types predefined by
>   Python only the immutable ones, such as strings, numbers, and tuples,
>   are hashable.** Mutable types, such as lists and dicts, are not hashable
>   because a change of their contents would change the hash and break the
>   lookup code.

I'm providing a set of strings here, so why is Python still complaining?

EDIT: after reading more into this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600462/unhashable-type-list-python), which recommends using `tuples`, I edited my collection object:

```
custom_stopwords = tuple(stopwords.words('english'))
```

I also realized I have to flatten my list, since `word_tokenize(sentence)` will create a list of lists, and will not filter out punctuation correctly (since a list object will not be in `custom_stopwords`, which is a list of strings.

However, this still begs the question- why are tuples considered hashable by Python but string sets not? And why does the `TypeError` say `list`?

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42203673/in-python-why-is-a-tuple-hashable-but-not-a-list) post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`words` is a *list of lists* since `word_tokenize()` returns a list of words.

When you do `[word for word in words if word not in custom_stopwords]` each `word` is actually of a `list` type. When the `word not in custom_stopwords` "is in set" condition needs to be checked, `word` needs to be hashed which fails because *lists are mutable containers and are not hashable in Python*.

These posts might help to understand what is "hashable" and why mutable containers are not:

- [In Python, why is a tuple hashable but not a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42203673/771848)
- [What do you mean by hashable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14535730/771848)
- [Hashable, immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2671376/771848)

Comment: Got it. It turns out that flattening the list:     `words = [word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
    flattened_words = [item for sublist in words for item in sublist]
    filtered_words = [word for word in flattened_words if word not in custom_stopwords]` is needed, since that converts `words` to a list of strings, not a list of lists. Once I flattened the list into a list of strings, I could use whatever collection I wanted to do my filtering (set, tuple, etc.)